# VB.NET CommanLineArgs Not Passing from Associated Filetype

Tags: .net, vb.net, clickonce, file-type, associated-types

I have a single-instance, ClickOnce WinForms app that has an associated file type.

when I run the app in debug, and manually input the command line args via debug settings, Everything works as expected.  The file specified in the debug args is processed and all goes to plan.

When I actually double-click an associated file type (either in debug, or live), the command line arg (%1) is not trasmitted to the app for some reason.  It just isn't there.
I do have the file extension set in my publish > options > file associations.
I do have the registry entries as follows:

```
rundll32.exe dfshim.dll, ShOpenVerbExtension {c0a5ac53-477c-4f76-bfc7-aa99e87cbe21} %1
```

This does in fact open the app when a file is double clicked.  the only thing missing is the sending filename (to be opened and processed).

Any ideas what may cause something like this to happen?

EDIT:  It may be important to note that the file is just a serialized object.  The intention is to deserialize and process the object once the file is double-clicked.  The logic to do this is already in place and working when I use a debug command line arg.

Environment.GetCommandLineArgs() returns only the path of the executable file in (0).

My.Application.CommandLineArgs.count = 0

Comment: Just in case:  I am checking for the args by both of the following:
  environment.getcommandlineargs()    AND   My.Application.CommandLineArgs.

Comment: When you say "It just isn't there", do you mean you are not getting any arguments. Or, is what you're expecting to happen not happening...and maybe you're getting arguments but not what you're expecting to get and therefore what you're expecting to happen doesn't?

Comment: Sorry for not including that clarity.  In my previous comment, I listed two methods of obtaining the args.  I do not see any args in those variables in my application events for startup or startupNextInstance.  commandlineargs.count = 0.

Answer (score 1):

### Update

Take a look at this link, [WPF: Supporting command line arguments and file extensions](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/avip/archive/2008/10/27/wpf-supporting-command-line-arguments-and-file-extensions.aspx). The code there is C#, but I think it should be straightforward to duplicate in VB.

> **Launching via a double-click on a custom file type.**
>
> I created an application that supports a custom document format and I
>   wanted a double-click on that document to open my application. I
>   assumed that the application would open normally with the document
>   presented as a command-line arg, but that’s not the case. Instead,
>   it’s stored in the following tongue-twister:
>
> ```
> AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ActivationArguments.ActivationData[0]
> ```

Comment: I copied that directly from my filetype in the registry.  It was added automatically via VS when I associated the filetype...   I'm assuming that the ShOpenVerbExtention maps to the correct file(it does match my GUID in the registry), and it does in fact open the program when I double click an associated file.   and the %1 (from what I'm reading) indicates the location of the file name aka arg

Comment: Since the program is opening I assume that the DLL & Entrypoint are correct as it is executing as expected.   is the %1 correct?  could it be something in my application setup that is blocking the arguments being passed to the program?

Comment: What registry key is that command line in? Are you sure that's the command that is executing when you double-click a file of that type?

Comment: It's found under the application name > shell > open > command > default REG_SZ (type).     According to my research this is the command issued by activating an associated file (doubleclick).  when I paste in the info (removing the %1) into 'run' it brings the program up as expected.

Comment: What happens if you paste the command in to the Run box and also include the path and file name that would be the parameter and then run it?

Comment: The application launches but the file was not processed.  I attached to the process and tried again via run, and it didn't hit my breakpoints on my application events (startup & startupnextinstance)..

Comment: Maybe `rundll32.exe dfshim.dll, ShOpenVerbExtension {c0a5ac53-477c-4f76-bfc7-aa99e87cbe21} %1` is finding a different version or copy of the file than you think it is? Can you try specifying the full path or make sure there are different versions in another folder, particularly a folder in the system `PATH`.

Comment: I meant to say "make sure there are _not_ different versions...".

Comment: I don't really know if I should be specifying the path to the server instance of the *.exe file or for the clickOnce *.application file ..  I tried both, and nothing happened at all.

Comment: @stevo22 After some research, I changed my answer...take a look.

Comment: I had actually came across that particular page previously.  The ActivationArguments object is not set ("Nothing").   I'm actually unable to test the "startup" event, since I can't attach to a process quick enough to catch it..  but on startupNextInstance, the ActivationArguments is Nothing.  :(

Comment: @stevo22 Maybe something in this question/answer will help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4233915/wpf-click-once-double-click-file-to-launch-vs-2008.

Comment: I currently have imported System.Deployment to namespace My

Comment: You can add this to your start script:
System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch()
It will force the app to ask you to attach a debugger.  If you add the Debugger.Break() on the next line it will wait until your debugger is attached and you press continue

Answer (score 0):

In Program - Properties Page - Under Publish - Options Button
   You Selected "File Associations"  say .mp3 or whatever. THIS, forces the program to be Opened by the ClickOnce Application Deployment Support Library - and not your program directly!

If you remove this and manually go in a select file associations, right click file and select open with - and use as default, then the %1 parameter in commandlineargs will be there.

Alternatively, if you don't want the user to do that. You need to get your command line arguments elsewhere - from the AppDomain. The following code will allow you to drag and drop multiple files on your app or allow you to double click.

```
    Dim strcmdLineArguments() as String = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs
    If AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ActivationArguments IsNot Nothing Then
        Dim addInfo() As String = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ActivationArguments.ActivationData
        i = strcmdLineArguments.Length
        ReDim Preserve strcmdLineArguments(i + addInfo.Length - 1)
        For j = 0 To addInfo.Length - 1
            strcmdLineArguments(i + j) = addInfo(j)
        Next
    End If
```

this should do the trick and your strcmdlinearguments should have what you want.
Forgot to add, the 0th element will still be your program's location